# Cannot access a disposed object while using different contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trapped with definitions of Entity framework and using objects. 
I am trying to save an uploaded file once I am saving the details related to that file in my database.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string List<IFormFile> files, [Bind("param")] Entity entity)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(entity);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();   

                //update Attachments
                if (files.Count > 0)
                {
                    attachment.UploadFiles(files);
                }
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!EntityExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(entity);
    }
```

When I run the application and want to submit the form I receive below error:
*Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'FileBufferingReadStream'.*

```
  [HttpPost]
    public async void UploadFiles(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        if (files == null || files.Count == 0)
        {
            log.error("files not selected");
        }
        try
        {
            List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
            string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\wwwroot";

            createDir(directory);

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                string filename = file.GetFilename();
                filenames.Add(filename);
            }
            if (filenames.Count > 0)
                foreach (var filename in filenames)
                {
                   AttachmentQ(filename, directory, createdBy);
                }
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                string filename = file.GetFilename();
                var path = Path.Combine(directory, filename);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
                filenames.Add(filename);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error(e.Message);

        }
    }

    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async void AttachmentQ(string filename, string path, string createdBy)
    {
        try
        {
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment
            {
                Name = filename,
                Path = path,
                CreatedBy = createdBy,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
            };

                _context.Add(attachment);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Surprisingly I don't get error in debug mode. But when I run the app I get *This page isn’t working* error.
I also noticed I need to return a value when I use async but I don't have any return vale in `UploadFiles()` and `AttachmentQ()` methods. 
Could you please help me how to handle objects when using different contexts.
 Thanks

Comment: So where exactly does your error occur?

Comment: Hey @WahidBitar. It worked well. Thanks. The only issue is that the page is not returned to Index page as requested in `Edit()` method so I get *This page isn’t working* error after.

Comment: if you don't have an async work in the method so don't add the async keyword to the method and just use `return Task.FromResult((object)null);` 
so your method will look like `public Task SomeMethod(){...
return Task.FromResult((object)null);}`

Comment: @FaridFarzin Please consider accepting my answer if it fits your question

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT use `async void` at all.

if you want to use async/await pattern then let your methods returns `Task`

`public async Task UploadFiles(List<IFormFile> files)`

Comment: If you don't know if this solves the problem then put it as a comment and ask the OP if it does or not. Then, if it does, post it with confidence.